# Apply Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle, inclusion-exclusion

I found the following exercise online:

A group of students passed exams. $41$ passed Exam $A$, $28$ passed Exam $B$, $26$ passed Exam $C$. Also, $11$ passed both, $A$ and $B$, $10$ passed $A$ and $C$ and $12$ passed $B$ and $C$. So in total $69$ passed at least one test. How many passed all $3$?

I read recently a bit about the pigeonhole principle and wondered if you could apply it to this problem. If so, how?

Comment: No, what you need here is [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: So, 7 would then be the solution since:
69 = 41 + 28 + 26 - 11 - 10 - 12 + x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you do not need the pigeonhole  principle here. Its a simple application of *cardinality of intersection of sets*.

You can find good information [here](https://byjus.com/maths/union-and-intersection-of-sets-cardinal-number-practical-problems/).

But what you need in short is the following

$$
\vert a\cup b\cup c\cup\vert = \vert a \vert + \vert b \vert + \vert c \vert - \vert a \cap b\vert - \vert a \cap c\vert - \vert c \cap b\vert +  \vert a \cup b \cup c\vert
$$

Hope this helped

Comment: Sure! Thanks a lot, I was again thinking way too complicated :)

Comment: @Avocari no problem mate, have a nice day!